# Insert the rows of 'report_temp' which are not in 'report'?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I've two tables :

```
report (reportID, VendorName, VendorID, MfgDate, PurchaseDate, etc.,)
```

In `report` table reportID is primary key.

`report_temp` has the **same set of columns** as `report`, but not any constraints.

I've to `insert the rows from report_temp to report` where the **reportID is not the same**.
I've written as

```
  INSERT INTO report(reportID, VendorName, VendorID, MfgDate, PurchaseDate,...) 
      NOT (SELECT reportID, VendorName, VendorID, MfgDate, PurchaseDate,... 
           FROM report INNER JOIN report_temp USING (reportID, VendorName, 
                VendorID, MfgDate,PurchaseDate,...))
```

I've also tried with just `reportID` within `USING` clause, but I can't get it... 
If you tried anything like this share with me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the set of reportIDs existing in *both* tables:

```
SELECT report_temp.reportID FROM report_temp, report WHERE report_temp.reportID=report.reportID
```

So this will give you the rows to insert:

```
SELECT * FROM report_temp WHERE reportID NOT IN (SELECT report_temp.reportID FROM report_temp, report WHERE report_temp.reportID=report.reportID)
```

Then just drop that into the `report` table:

```
INSERT INTO report SELECT * FROM report_temp WHERE reportID NOT IN (SELECT report_temp.reportID FROM report_temp, report WHERE report_temp.reportID=report.reportID)
```